# SingleChildScrollView makes the UI white

Tags: flutter, scroll

I am trying to make my UI scrollable but when i add the SingleChildScrollView i get this white screen not showing anything at all.I should erase the Column from the begining?Use a container?I already search on internet but i don't know what to add.
Here is my code, please tell me what i can erase or add to make it work ..

```
class _UserProfilesState extends State<UserProfiles> {

  @override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 40.0),
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                            iconSize: 30.0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          ),
                        ])),
                Positioned(
                  left: 24,
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6.5 - 28,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 84,
                    width: 84,

                    //profilepic
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 10,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.avatarUrl != null
                          ? widget.avatarUrl
                          : "https://icon-library.com/images/add-image-icon/add-image-icon-14.jpg"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right: 24,
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6.5 + 16,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 32,
                        width: 100,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ChatScreen(
                                        serviceProviderId:
                                            widget.serviceProviderId,
                                        userName: widget.userName,
                                        avatarUrl: widget.avatarUrl,
                                      )));
                            },
                            color: Colors.black,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            child: Text(
                              "Message",
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 16,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 32,
                        width: 32,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Kf8WTct65hFJxBUDm5E-EpYsiDoLQiGGbnuyP6HBNax43YShXti9THPon1YKB6zPYpA"),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: Colors.blue),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                    left: 24,
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4.3,
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(widget.userName,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 22,
                              )),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: Text(
                                widget.address == "default"
                                    ? "No Address yet"
                                    : "${widget.address}",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                ),
                              )),
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "${widget.categoryName}",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))
              ],
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your UI became white is that `SingleChildScrollView` allows it child to take as much space as possible. In your `Column`, one of your children is `Expanded`, `Expanded` tries to take as much space as possible. You are making your UI take an infinite amount of space because of that. That's the reason why you are seeing a white screen. **The solution here would be to remove `Expanded`.**

Comment: what i should put instead expanded? or what i should add because now i get only this https://imgur.com/a/2O65jYJ

Comment: @svraluca1 I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here but I don't think you would need to use stack in your scenario.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mN3T1nf to achive this but scrollable

Comment: Have a Listview with one back button, one row, then the rest for text

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/u7brO1U it's messing with all them in the page now

Comment: Can you update your code above? Also, you have to set the alignment of ListView to alignment.left

Answer (score 2):

Using Spacer() might also cause this issue

Comment: In my case i was using a spacer(flex = 1) in a Column

Answer (score 0):

according to me and the knowledge I have this happened because the singlechildscrollview here tries to take as much height as it can take so It is creating an issue to solve this wrap the singlechildscrollview in a container and give height&width to the container it solved in my case

Thanks...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please re-format your answer using punctuation and sentences so it is readable. Also, it would be helpful if you could explain how your answer is different than the answer already provided by CoderUni.

Comment: There isn't enough information to distinguish this answer from the other one for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues, but after much research I got it working, by ensuring that the body of the scaffold be a Container that defines it's height and width, or Column. After which you can wrapped your any of these with a SingleChildScrollView.

However, in an attempt to insert an Expanded widget as child element, the expanded widget will look for bounded heights of it's parents/root element. And if it doesn't found any, it will thrown an error. A good example is if the root element is a column or a container with an unbounded height. Which is your case, looking at your code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).